# Using WCF Windows Named Pipes with Docker Containers

Tags: c#, docker, wcf, named-pipes

I have been attempting to connect to a docker container locally which is running a named pipe console application.  I cannot connect to my named pipe from my local computer via the docker container.  I have followed the snippets online I have found to do this by declaring the volume in the docker run for the named pipe, but I am kind of stumped on how to get this to work.  Below is an example of the code I am using.

Console Application Entry Point

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                using (var host = new ServiceHost(new DiscoveryProxyService(), "net.pipe://localhost/testname"))
            {
                ServiceDiscoveryProxyEndpointConfigurator.Configure(host, endpointConfig);
                host.Open();
            }
         }
```

My Docker File looks like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
SHELL ["powershell"]

RUN Install-WindowsFeature -name NET-WCF-Pipe-Activation45
RUN Install-WindowsFeature -name NET-WCF-TCP-Activation45
RUN Install-WindowsFeature -name NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45

# Next, this Dockerfile creates a directory for your application
WORKDIR WcfDiscoveryProxyTest

# Copies the site you published earlier into the container.
COPY WcfDiscoveryProxyTest/ .

# start WCFTCPSElfHost service process in container as entrypoint process.
ENTRYPOINT .\bin\Debug\WcfDiscoveryProxyTest.exe
```

My Docker commands are the following

```
docker build -t test:latest .
docker run -d -itd -v \\.\pipe\localhost\testname:\\.\pipe\localhost\testname test:latest
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the code working as desired outside of docker? Meaning, are you certain it's docker configuration that's the issue?

Comment: @CoolBots yep.  If I run the service locally I can connect successfully.  This is running via the visual studio debugger.

Comment: Have you tried to replace localhost with the full machine name in your configuration?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that for the application running in the container, `localhost` is the container, not your local machine.  If you use `localhost` there, it will be looking for other things running in the container.  Consider using something that can manage your network connections, like Docker Compose or Docker's built in Kubernetes to allow connections to the container to work.  I had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461691/asp-net-core-web-api-service-cannot-connect-to-docker-sql-server-on-same-network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid, you're out of luck. WCF supports named pipes only on the same machine...

> [...] the netNamedPipeBinding binding, which provides cross-process communication on the same machine. Named pipes do not work across machines.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/netnamedpipebinding

This will (most likely) also apply to docker containers.