# VS React-Redux container connecting to api-sqlserver containers

Tags: windows, docker, api, react-redux, containers

Got a problem with VS React-Redux template deployed as a docker container connecting to api docker container. Below are the given facts:

Fact 1. I've got 3 Docker Windows containers in docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/solomiosisante/test):

1. solomiosisante/test:sqlserver
2. solomiosisante/test:api
3. solomiosisante/test:react

Fact 2. I managed to make the api connect to sqlserver and make them communicate by creating a docker nat network. API container can get and display data from the sqlserver container.

Fact 3. I also run the react container using the same nat network.

Fact 4. I can successfully docker run the react container.

Fact 5. They are all running Net 5.0 (VS projects), but not sure with sqlserver because I just got it from microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer image.

Fact 6. I can run the react project from visual studio and load the pages in the browser with no problem. (and it connects to api container)

**Problem:** I could not make the react container browse to any of my pages. Browser says it can't be reached connection timed out.

**React project Dockerfile:**

```
# escape=`
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

###########################################################################################
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:nanoserver-1903 AS downloadnodejs
RUN mkdir -p C:\nodejsfolder
WORKDIR C:\nodejsfolder
SHELL ["pwsh", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v15.6.0/node-v15.6.0-win-x64.zip"; `
Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\; `
Rename-Item "C:\node-v15.6.0-win-x64" c:\nodejs

###########################################################################################
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

###########################################################################################
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
RUN mkdir -p C:\nodejs
COPY --from=downloadnodejs C:\nodejs\ C:\nodejs

# needs to use ContainerAdministrator to be able to setx path
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\nodejs"
USER ContainerUser
RUN echo %PATH%
#RUN echo "%PATH%"
#RUN echo $PATH
#RUN echo {$PATH}

WORKDIR /src
#COPY ["Consequence.React/Consequence.React.csproj", "Consequence.React/"]
#COPY ["Consequence.API/Consequence.API.csproj", "Consequence/"]
#COPY ["Consequence.EF/Consequence.EF.csproj", "Consequence.EF/"]
#COPY ["Consequence.Repositories/Consequence.Repositories.csproj", "Consequence.Repositories/"]

COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "Consequence.React/Consequence.React.csproj"

#WORKDIR "/src/Consequence.React/ClientApp"
#RUN npm install
#RUN npm audit fix
WORKDIR "/src/Consequence.React"
RUN dotnet build "Consequence.React.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

WORKDIR /src
RUN dir /s

WORKDIR "/src/Consequence.React"

###########################################################################################
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Consequence.React.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

###########################################################################################
FROM base AS final
RUN mkdir -p C:\nodejs
COPY --from=downloadnodejs C:\nodejs\ C:\nodejs

# needs to use ContainerAdministrator to be able to setx path
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\nodejs"
USER ContainerUser

RUN echo %PATH%

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN dir /s

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" 
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=8089
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44319 
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="P@ssw0rd123" 
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/src/certs/consequence.pfx

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Consequence.React.dll"]
```

Any ideas, questions, please comment. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by using isolation=process. I thought I've got so much trouble with Hyper-V and can do without it. I followed the article [Docker on Windows without Hyper-V](https://poweruser.blog/docker-on-windows-10-without-hyper-v-a529897ed1cc) by Chris and updated my [docker hub test repo](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/solomiosisante/test). I also put the instructions there on how to make it work. Please check [this](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/solomiosisante/test) out. I now have docker images I can use as a base image for my future Docker-React-Redux docker deployment using Windows Containers. I hope this helps those who have encountered the same problems like me.